# search database and checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I got such code

```
   $query = $_GET['query']; 


$min_length = 0;


if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);




       if(isset($_POST['option1']) && 
          $_POST['option1'] == 'Yes') 
         {
  $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE (type = 'hotel' ) AND ((`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%'))    ");
          }
            if(isset($_POST['option2']) && 
         $_POST['option2'] == 'Yes') 
          {
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE  (type = 'restaurant' )  AND((`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%')) ");
     } 
    else{
      $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE (`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%')   ");
             }
```

and form

```
    <form action="results.php" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Yes"> hotel<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Yes" > restaurant

      <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
```

I also got Mysql database with 'type' field. but it doesnt work 100% properly.
When I use search and i check restaurant checkbox I want to have search only from restaurants, and the same with 'hotel'. But script search without checked fields, just returns searched phrase. Can you see any mistakes ?

Comment: WHEN are people going to learn to debug??

Comment: And don't use deprecated mysql-functions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

result.php:

```
   $query = $_GET['query']; 


$min_length = 0;


if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);




       if(isset($_GET['option1']) && 
          $_GET['option1'] == 'Yes') 
         {
  $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE (type = 'hotel' ) AND ((`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%'))    ");
          }
            if(isset($_GET['option2']) && 
         $_GET['option2'] == 'Yes') 
          {
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE  (type = 'restaurant' )  AND((`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%')) ");
     } 
    else{
      $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE (`object` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pass` LIKE '%".$query."%')   ");
   }
```

Form :

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">
 <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Yes"> hotel<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Yes" > restaurant

  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

**Important I haven't tested any of your code. Just my first thoughts when I saw your code.**  Recommendation change checkbox into Radiobox, because it is either hotels or restaurants. Changed POST into GET. You were using GET and POST together, this is highly unlikely. I would recommend using mysqli_* or PDO for connection to database instead of the depreciated mysql_* functions.